# Check if website is in client's trusted sites

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to check if users are following our instructions and adding our site to their list of trusted sites in internet explorer. The list of trusted sites is stored in the registry of the client and checking the registry problematically in asp.net is as far as I know not possible

Is there anyway to check if the site is trusted in asp.net? Even it is a test page that will error if it's not trusted.

Comment: What happens in IE if the site isn't trusted?  ActiveX components don't automatically run?  You can place an ActiveX component on a page, see if the component responds, and send the user an error message if it doesn't.

Comment: I would do the opposite to what @bdares is saying: Display an error message *by default* in the page, in plain-old HTML/CSS... and using an ActiveX that requires the site be in the Trusted Sites in order to *remove* the error and use the site normally. Sort of the same principle as the `<noscript>` tag: It's normal HTML for non-javascript browsers, and gets displayed; Javascript browsers treat is specially and *remove* that element from display.

Comment: Good point.  Takes out the possibility of your component malfunctioning and the user just sitting there with a normal-looking and non-functioning UI.